# How to extract all strings from re.findall() list to be converted into integers?

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing some text and trying to retrieve all the numbers from the text and then gather their sum. I used a regex `re.findall([0-9]+)` and have retrieved the numbers successfully, but am having trouble converting ALL OF the retrieved numbers into integers. The below code returns an incorrect sum because it will only add the first number that appears in each line of the text. Below is the full code.

```
import re
fname=raw_input('Whats up?')
fh=open(fname, 'r')
y=list()
count=0

    for line in fh:
        y=re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
        inp=list(y)
        if y == []:
            continue
        count=count+int(y[0])
print count
```

Comment: Try `count += sum([int(i) for i in y])`

Comment: @JamieBull Perfect! That gave me the right sum! So if I'm understanding that line of code correctly, it first loops through each element in y, converts into an integer, and then the sum() function adds each integerized element "i" together, eventually adding it to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only adds the first number of each line only because you asked it to. I am assuming you have multiple numbers in a line.

y=re.findall('[0-9]+', line) <- parsed and returns a list of all the number in the line.

all you need is another loop to sum up all the value in that list.

replace count = count +int(y[0])

with

```
for yy in y:
    count = count + int(yy)
```

or

```
count = count + sum(map(int,y))
```

you should be able to see the correct sum.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!